# How to open and edit the pdf file uploaded by form

Tags: python, django

I have `ModelViewSet` class which accepts the uploaded file.
using pymupdf( pdf handling library)

```
import fitz

class DrawingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.Drawing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.DrawingSerializer
    def list(self, request):
        serializer = s.DrawingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
        
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #file is uploaded as 'drawing'

        print(request.FILES) # <MultiValueDict: {'drawing': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: mypdf.pdf>]}>
        print(request.FILES['drawing']) # mypdf.pdf
        doc = fitz.open(request.FILES['drawing'])
        



class Drawing(models.Model):
    drawing = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  


class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    drawing = serializers.FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = m.Drawing
        fields = ('id','drawing')
```

When I uploaded the file, there comes the error like this.

```
fitz.fitz.FileNotFoundError: no such file: 'mypdf.pdf'
```

Comment: Please show code of serializers. What is `request.data` ? What is drawing in `request.data` ?. Could you post the complete trace ?

Comment: I added the `Serializer` to article. request is the form from the browser, request.data['drawing']  has the file name, but not file data itself.

Comment: And I found I should use `request.FILES` instead of `request.data`, however result doesn't change.

Comment: Can you post the complete trace ?